# Twilio ChatApp - post webhook is not adding me when OnConversationAdded webhook fires off to my ngrok url

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

The title says it all. My goal is for a User to send an SMS to my Twilio Number and to be able to Chat back via ChatApp.

I'm using the Twilio ChatApp from Codesource and Ngrok reserved domain.
My tunnel is working and Twilio log shows Status was received but it seems like my webhook isn't firing off to add me to the conversation. I know the code is correct because its straight from Codesandbox.

When I do a terminal twilio-cli command to Create Participant (ident) with Chat Service SID that was created upon incoming text, the ChatApp works fine and I'm added in.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Having just come up with this myself, I believe that this Twilio webhook only fires in response to a 200 of onConversationAdd, not all conversations, as you may assume.

This in turn is only called as part of auto-creation.

Therefore, check that auto-creation is enabled, but also that the phone number isn't already part of a conversation, else it won't go into auto-creation too.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. You are correct and I do have it setup accordingly, but I'll admit early in my adventure knowing that I had to delete my # after each test was learned after a few days lol.

I think my issue may be within ngrok being configured correctly but I doubt because well... ngrok isn't difficult to setup.